# Why does alert(++[[]][+[]]+[+[]]); print 10?

Tags: javascript

If you run
`alert(++[[]][+[]]+[+[]]);` code in js then it will alert `10`.Why is that? What logic does this code use?

Comment: This is a near exact duplicate of an old question. Will probably be hard to find though. This style is called "JSFuck" though btw. Read up on it.

Comment: http://www.jsfuck.com/ Read the bottom.

Comment: @Carcigenicate oh thanks

Comment: @Ivan no idea.People probably thought i'm faking

Comment: @Ivan Probably because there's no effort shown. If you broke this down, it would be possible to reverse engineer bits of it.

Comment: Yeah, but it sounds more like a a brain-teaser to me ;)

Answer (score 3):

Check out [jsfuck.com](http://www.jsfuck.com/). This gives examples and shows how to, quite literally, write any code using it.

The basics:

```
false       =>  ![]
true        =>  !![]
undefined   =>  [][[]]
NaN         =>  +[![]]
0           =>  +[]
1           =>  +!+[]
2           =>  !+[]+!+[]
10          =>  [+!+[]]+[+[]]
Array       =>  []
Number      =>  +[]
String      =>  []+[]
Boolean     =>  ![]
Function    =>  []["filter"]
eval        =>  []["filter"]["constructor"]( CODE )()
window      =>  []["filter"]["constructor"]("return this")()
```

Comment: [The license](https://github.com/aemkei/jsfuck/blob/master/LICENSE.txt) _is_ pretty permissive, so that should be no problem.